# Trigonometric identitiess

Tags: trigonometry

I was in class today and we were proving identities, my teacher told me I was correct, but I should be careful as sin x doesn't always equal  1/cosec x

Why is this

Comment: Perhaps when cosec x = 0

Comment: @arberavdullahu $\csc(x) = 0$ doesn't have any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(x) = \frac{1}{\csc(x)}$ in any case.

It's can be a logical statement if you're worried about the $\frac10$ case, but it is false.

Perhaps your teacher was worried about the $\csc(x) = 0$ case, but there is [no such $x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=csc(x)%20%3D%200) for which this applies.

Comment: does this mean it's a valid statement for an x

Comment: @user376253 Yes, since $\sin a = \cos (\frac\pi2-a) = \frac1{\csc a}$ using the identities for goniometric functions.

Comment: Hi, I emailed my teacher and he said that I'm mistaken. He claims he said cot x doesn't always equal 1/tan x

Comment: could you explain why

Comment: @user376253 Ah, in that case you're teacher is right. That's because $\tan(x) = 0$ _is_ possible. Namely for $x = \pi$, you get a division by zero if you do that. Both $\frac{1}{\tan(\pi)}$ and $\cot(\pi)$ are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The *purely symbolic* relationship $sin(x) = 1 / csc(x)$ always holds.  As I learned it, this is because $csc(x)$ is *defined* as $1 / sin(x)$.  However, as *functions* they are not equal *for every value of x*: wherever $sin(x)$ is zero, $csc(x)$ is **undefined** (due to divide-by-zero).  That is what the teacher is referring to.